# issue with text search critera

Tags: sql

I'm just getting into SQL. Little confused ate the following. maybe you can help. This query works

```
SELECT topics.topic FROM topics 
LEFT JOIN daybook 
ON topics.topic_id = daybook.topic_id
WHERE daybook.daybook_id = 7
```

where as this query fails

```
SELECT topics.topic FROM topics 
LEFT JOIN daybook 
ON topics.topic_id = daybook.topic_id
WHERE daybook.test = “test text”
```

I don't understand why. daybook.test is a string field. It's being passed a string. I've tried all varieties if writing with no improvement. Can you help?

thanks
G

Comment: We can't see your schema, but as a thought, are you sure it's not daybook.text instead of daybook.test?

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes, not double quotes, to delimit your SQL string literals.  In other words use 'test text' in this case.

Comment: @giles: Could you please elaborate with regard to *still failing*? Was there an error? Or the results just were incorrect? Or something else? It would also be nice if you were more specific about your original problem (where you are not using single quotes) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes around like this 'test text'

```
SELECT topics.topic FROM topics 
LEFT JOIN daybook 
ON topics.topic_id = daybook.topic_id
WHERE daybook.test = 'test text';
```

Important:

You must have to use ''(single quotes) around your varchar value in sql/mysql. However in case of int, the query works same with and without single quotes

Reason:

if you don't use '' around varchar your query **takes it as a variable**. So gives error